# How to find out matching number and string in a text file using C#

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I am trying to read a string from a TEXT File inside the quotation ' ', which is a filepath. If the line contains "SSiJobPage:" and if it's matches the  number next to it. Like If the line contains 'SSiJobPage: 8', then got to the line where  'SSiJobFileRef: 8' and get the file path next to it which is 'C:\folderName\012M032.filename.p1.pdf'. Also it will run until find all the 'SSiJobPage:'  How can I do that in C#?

Thanks so much in advance!!

```
>%SSiJobFileRef: 2 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p1.pdf' 2 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 3 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p2.pdf' 3 -1 0 0.00000  
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 4 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p3.pdf' 4 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 5 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p4.pdf' 5 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 6 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p5.pdf' 6 -1 0 0.00000
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 7 'C:\folderName\210C001-3.filename.p6.pdf' 7 -1 0 0.00000  
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 8 'C:\folderName\012M032.filename.p1.pdf' 8 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 9 'C:\folderName\002M052.filename.p1.pdf' 9 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 10 'C:\folderName\012M042.filename.p1.pdf' 10 -1 0 0.00000  
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 11 'C:\folderName\002W000.filename.p1.pdf' 11 -1 0 0.00000  
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 12 'C:\folderName\012B000.filename.p1.pdf' 12 -1 0 0.00000 
        >%SSiJobFileRef: 13 'C:\folderName\002W100.filename.p1.pdf' 13 -1 0 0.00000 
        >
        >%SSiJobPage: 8 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 9 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 10 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 2 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 3 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 11 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 12 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 4 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 5 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 13 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 14 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 6 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 7 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 15 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 16 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 17 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 8 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 21 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 10 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0 
        >%SSiJobPage: 18 1 0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.00000 3 0.00000 0.00000 '' 0
```

Comment: When you don't have any answer, then don't comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like so:

```
public class SSiJob
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public bool matched { get; set; }
}

        List<SSiJob> jobs = new List<SSiJob>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\CYA\Test2.txt"))
        {
            string stringy;
            while ((stringy = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = stringy.TrimStart().Split(' ');
                if (words[0] == ">%SSiJobFileRef:")
                {
                   jobs.Add(new SSiJob { id = Convert.ToInt32(words[1]), path = words[2] });

                }
                else if (words[0] == ">%SSiJobPage:")
                {
                    var check = jobs.Where(a => a.id == Convert.ToInt32(words[1])).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(check != null)
                    {
                        check.matched= true;
                    }
                }
            }
            jobs.RemoveAll(a => a.matched == false);
        }
```